# Given 2 points, return a 3rd point between them that is closer to the first point given

Tags: python, math, geometry

Given 2 points `A(x1,y1,z1)` and `B(x2,y2,z2)`, return `C(x3,y3,z3)` that is on the line AB but is closer to A.

```
A ----C----------------B
```

In 3D space.

Using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a point that lies one third of the way between A and B.

```
def thirdPoint(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):
    x3 = (x2-x1)/3.0 + x1
    y3 = (y2-y1)/3.0 + y1
    z3 = (z2-z1)/3.0 + z1
    return x3, y3, z3
```

Comment: Thank a lot! Works ;)

Comment: You're welcome! If you're satisfied with the answer, can you please give it the green checkmark?